# iOS: NSObject data mapping error

Tags: ios, pagination, tableview

hi **iOS community** 
I read similar questions but unable to find a solution 
I started work on modelling  a sub-class of NSObject
but mapping is giving me some error, I don't understand this logic, Please help me understand

```
#import "Listing_Ads.h"

@implementation Listing_Ads


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Properties Synthesized

@synthesize     title_value =   _title_value;
@synthesize     desc_value  =   _desc_value;
@synthesize     location    =   _location;
@synthesize     amount      =   _amount ;
@synthesize     date        =   _date;
@synthesize     image       =   _image;



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Data_Allocation

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@" Titles are:%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"title"]);
        self.title_value    =   [dictionary  valueForKey:@"title"];
        self.desc_value     =   [dictionary  valueForKey:@"description"];
        self.location       =   [dictionary  valueForKey:@"city_name"];
        self.amount         =   [dictionary  valueForKey:@"amount"];
        self.image          =   [dictionary  valueForKey:@"my_images"];
    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

```
  [manager GET:urlstring parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

         _totalPages = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"totalPages"]integerValue];

         for (int i=0;i<[[responseObject valueForKey:@"items"]count];i++)

         {
             NSLog(@"Number of items are:%d",[[responseObject valueForKey:@"items"]count]);

             Listing_Ads * ads = [[Listing_Ads alloc] initWithDictionary:[responseObject valueForKey:@"items"]];

            if (![self.ads_Array containsObject:ads])
             {
                 [self.ads_Array addObject:ads];
             }


         }
```

In response I am getting 10 values each property defined in `Listing_Ads`

error is :

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7cadabc0
```

Comment: I suppose [responseObject valueForKey:@"items"] return NSArray. So in line [[Listing_Ads alloc] initWithDictionary:[responseObject valueForKey:@"items"]];
 you pass NSArray instead NSDictionary.

Comment: Just add [[Listing_Ads alloc] initWithDictionary:[responseObject valueForKey:@"items"][i]];

Comment: works with charm...
thanks